# "Run time error '9' Subscript out of range" shows up while trying to fetch the Email body from outlook to Excel file

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to fetch the part of the Email body from outlook to Excel file using the following coding. It is giving me error as  `“Run time error '9' Subscript out of range “`  as specified in the coding below. Would someone please review my code below and help me out. Thank you

My Code:

```
Sub try()
Dim vText As Variant

Dim sText As String

Dim vItem As Variant

Dim str2 As String

Dim subject As String

Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application

Set mynamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("mapi")

Set myfolder = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Set xlobj = New Excel.Application

xlobj.Visible = True

xlobj.Workbooks.Add

xlobj.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Statusmail"

xlobj.Range("A1").Value = "Caller Name"

xlobj.Range("B1").Value = "Caller Requirement"

xlobj.Range("C1").Value = "Caller Phone"

xlobj.Range("D1").Value = "Caller Company"

xlobj.Range("E1").Value = "Caller Email"

xlobj.Range("F1").Value = "Call Date & Time"

xlobj.Range("G1").Value = "Branch Info"

xlobj.Range("H1").Value = "City"

 For i = 1 To myfolder.Items.Count

  Set myItem = myfolder.Items(i)

  msgtext = myItem.Body

  sText = myItem.Body

  subject = myItem.subject

  If InStr(1, subject, "enquiry for you", vbTextCompare) Then

  vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))

    For j = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1

      If ((InStr(1, vText(j), "Caller Name:") > 0) Or (InStr(1, vText(j), "Name :") > 0)) Then

            vItem = vText(j + 1)

            xlobj.Range("A" & i + 1).Value = Trim(vItem)

        End If
       If InStr(1, vText(j), "Caller Requirement:") > 0 Then

            vItem = vText(j + 1)

            xlobj.Range("B" & i + 1).Value = Trim(vItem)

        End If
        If ((InStr(1, vText(j), "Caller Phone:") > 0) Or (InStr(1, vText(j), "Phone :") > 0)) Then

            vItem = vText(j + 1)

            xlobj.Range("C" & i + 1).Value = Trim(vItem)

        End If
        If InStr(1, vText(j), "Caller Company:") > 0 Then

            vItem = vText(j + 1)

            xlobj.Range("D" & i + 1).Value = Trim(vItem)

        End If
        If InStr(1, vText(j), "Caller Email:") > 0 Then

            vItem = vText(j + 1)
            If Not IsEmpty(vItem) Then
            Dim str1 As String
            If InStr(1, vItem, ":") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vItem, Chr(58))
            str1 = vItem(1)
            End If
            vItem = Split(str1, Chr(34))
         ' BELOW LINE GIVES ERROR  
            xlobj.Range("E" & i + 1).Value = vItem(0)   ' THIS LINE IS GIVING ERROR
            End If

        End If
        If ((InStr(1, vText(j), "Call Date & Time:") > 0) Or (InStr(1, vText(j), "Call Date :") > 0)) Then

            vItem = vText(j + 1)

            xlobj.Range("F" & i + 1).Value = Trim(vItem)

        End If
        If InStr(1, vText(j), "Branch Info:") > 0 Then

            vItem = vText(j + 1)

            xlobj.Range("G" & i + 1).Value = Trim(vItem)

        End If
        If ((InStr(1, vText(j), "City:") > 0) Or (InStr(1, vText(j), "City Name :") > 0)) Then

            vItem = vText(j + 1)

            xlobj.Range("H" & i + 1).Value = Trim(vItem)

        End If
       Next
  End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: At which line you get the error ?

Comment: I have mentioned in the code as comment which line is giving error.Thank you for checking it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this line:

```
If InStr(1, vItem, ":") > 0 Then
```

doesn't meet criteria than this line will be executed next

```
vItem = Split(str1, Chr(34))
```

which in fact trying to split empty `str1 variable`. As a result your Array is empty causing 
`Run-time error'9'` referring to right part of the next line:

```
xlobj.Range("E" & i + 1).Value = vItem(0)
```

So, `VItem(0)` is your problem while it doesn't exist.

Comment: I checked the condition "If IsEmpty(str1) ". Now it is not giving any error but still it doesn't write any data on the Excel file although using add watch I can see all the data is read.

Comment: I see you don't check `If IsEmpty(str1) ` but you check `If IsEmpty(vItem) ` in your code...

Comment: I checked If `IsEmpty(str1)` before the line `vItem = Split(str1, Chr(34))` and now it is working fine. Thanks alot.